# Salesforce: Syntax Help

Tags: visualforce, pdf

Can someone help me with my syntax. I am creating a visualforce page that renders as a pdf. The text should be red (#c73c3c) and the underline should be black. So far this gives me red text with red underline.

```
<div style="padding-left:5px; color:#c73c3c; text-decoration: underline; text-decoration-color:black;">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As near as I can tell, you're not doing anything wrong, it's simply not supported. [Flying Saucer](https://github.com/flyingsaucerproject/flyingsaucer), the underlying technology, only has spotty support for CSS3.

As an alternative, if you *must* have it look just that way, you can:

```
<div style="padding-left:5px; color:#c73c3c;">
    <span style="border-bottom: 1px solid black">Insert text here</span>
</div>
```

Which should give you a pretty decent approximation of a black underline. Feel free to adjust the style as you like.